# Compare and Multiply

Tags: google-sheets

I want to compare two cells and obtain a percentage, for instance:

A1 is `190`
B1 is `200`
C1 is the answer

I tried:

```
 B1 >= A1
```

but the answer is `TRUE`.

I will create a report if cell B1 s greater than cell A1 then:

IF YES I need to get the 12% percent of cell B1 and the answer would appear on cell C1

IF NOT the value for cell C1 would be `0.00`.

Can anyone help me to create a syntax for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `=IF(B1>=A1,B1*0.12,0)`

check snap below

[image]

And for formatting you can select column, right click - Format Cells - select `Number` and keep 2 Decimal places.